# How to prevent Gmail from adding anchor tags

Tags: html, gmail

I am sending out HTML emails via Amazon SES.

Here's an example email -

> Hey John doe,
>
> Uncle Sam has just applied for the job **need someone to post on
>   craigs list.com** you posted on JobHouse.
>
> Cheers.

Now, Gmail (and maybe other email clients) add a hyperlink to the `list.com`. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

Server-side solution:

Surround all **dots** (".") and **at-signs** ("@") with **Zero-Width Space** characters.

Example (PHP):

```
$email = 'name@server.com';
$email = str_replace (
                        array('@', '.'),
                        array('&#8203;@&#8203;', '&#8203;.&#8203;'),
                        $email
);
```

Alternatively, you may use a Unit-Separator (`&#31;`) or a Record-Separator (`&#30;`), instead of the zero-width space character (`&#8203;`) above.

Visually, the email / website address will seem normal, as before the replacements.

**Note**: replacing dots & at-signs with their html codes (`&#46;` & `&#64;` respectively) does not solve the problem. Gmail's algorithm still interprets string as an address.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding when you are sending out the email, if you are not creating the hyperlinks in your HTML content then you have no control over how the client renders the content.  If someone views the email with Gmail, Outlook, Mail, etc. and they notice a "pattern" they determine as a URL, the client application will replace the values.

- One thing you can do is generate an image of the domain name instead
  and reference that to completely control how it is rendered.

SEE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

You could create a simple PHP script for example and pass in the web address as URL parameters and it returns an image with that URL.  You then change your HTML code and instead:

```
<img src="domain.com/path/to/your/text.php?text=craigslist.com" />
```

Aside from doing something like this, there is no way you can control how the client application will render your text.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use `<text>yoururl.com</text>` in your email generation.

Though I'm not 100% on if it'll work in GMail as I have nothing to test with to hand currently.

Comment: Does it have to be the URL you use? Could you not just say Craigslist for example?

Comment: `need someone to post on craigs list.com` is the title of the job. So that part is dynamic in all the emails that are sent.

Comment: Ah right. Are you expecting the dynamic part to always contain a URL?